# Change notification intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications

I have a service that shows a notification that I wish that will be able to go to a specific activity of my app each time the user presses on it. Usually it would be the last one that the user has shown, but not always.

If the activity was started before, it should return to it, and if not, it should open it inside of the app's task, adding it to the activities tasks.

In addition, on some cases according to the service's logic, I wish to change the notification's intent so that it will target a different activity.

How do i do that? Is it possible without creating a new notification and dismissing the previous one? Is it also possible without creating a new task or an instance of an activity?

Comment: i always try . sorry if it doesn't seem this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wouldn't be possible to change the Activity once you have sent the notification.

You can start an Activity on your task stack that is not a problem, check out the notification service in the tutorial here:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

You have to set a pending intent on the notification:

```
        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class), 0);

        // Set the info for the view that shows in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);
```

You can see the pending intent takes a normal intent "`new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class`" so if you want specific behaviour (like bringing to the top instead of starting a new activity. Add the flags like you would normally to this intent. i.e. [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) ([something like that](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html))

Comment: so you say i can't modify the intent of the notification ? is it also true on newer versions of android , which have a different way to create notifications?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes you can't modify it after you have sent it to the system. You can send different notifications though, that is fine

Comment: i see .how come this is impossible , but changing the views in the notification is possible ? i even saw an app that shows a updating graph inside the notification . was sure it's impossible since i thought that it's very limited in functionality, just like appWidgets.

Comment: @androiddeveloper if you think its possible, go try it. Come back to stackoverflow when you have some code that does/doesn't work

Comment: i believe you . it's just a weird thing . thank you for your help . you'll get "V" now and also a +1 . :)

Answer (score 1):

Since platform version 11, you can build a notification using Notification.Builder. The v4 support library has an equivalent class NotificationCompat.Builder.

You can't change the Activity once you've sent the notification, but you can update the notification with a new Intent. When you create the PendingIntent, use the flag FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT. When you send the new notification, use the ID of the existing notification when you call NotificationManager.notify().

Also, you should be careful how you start your app. The Status Bar Notifications guide tells you how to set up the back stack.

Comment: not sure i understand . in what way can you change the intent of the notification? is it possible to add/modify that extra data of the intent? how would you make it to go to any activity you wish ? by adding the activity's class name to the extra data?