# Start/Resume application when a notification is clicked

Tags: android, notifications

I have a custom application that has multiple activities running in full screen (`SplashActivity`, `MainActivity`, `InfoActivity`, and so on...). I'm currently working on notifications and i'm trying to have the following behavior: if the application is running and put to background and the user clicks the notification, the last activity that was running resumes. If the user is not running the application, then the `SplashActivity` is launched. Is there a way to have this behavior? I'm using the following code

```
android.app.NotificationManager notificationManager = (android.app.NotificationManager) instance.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(instance, SplashActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(instance, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(instance);

    builder.setSmallIcon(iconId);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

If i set the activity to SplashActivity.class it will open that activity whether the application was running or not, so that would only be right if the application was not running.

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955484/change-notification-intent-in-android)

Comment: this helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305088/how-to-make-notification-intent-resume-rather-than-making-a-new-intent/39482464#39482464

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is the default behavior that the `OS` will perform on your application **Unless the OS needs memory and your application in the backStack** . In this case the `OS` will force close your application if it was in the background.

**So,** you cannot depend on the `OS` in this situation. You can handle it manually using the `SharedPreference` to store your current state of the application and check it when your `notification` is being clicked or your application is being opened.

Here is an [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/) of how to use the `SharedPreference` to keep a state of your app

Comment: I've updated my question to state that my default behaviour does not do that, because i have to specify an activity to launch in the intent when i click the notification, so it will always open that activity instead of resuming the last activity opened before the application was put in the background, in the case where the application was already running.

Answer (score 0):

You may create your class, which extends Application with stack or array of your activities. And in onStop() of activities you may change order